# How does the linking process affect the system and library calls in Linux?

Tags: linux, linker, relationship, system-calls

I've been looking for information about a relationship between the linking process and the calls but I didn't find any useful information. I would be very grateful if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

Not really clear what you are asking.

The "linking process" connects up references between different compilation units and objects.  When those references are function calls, it links them up so code in one compilation unit calls the code in another.

System calls happen in some code.  When the system call is in a library and the library function is called from another compilation unit (common case), it links up the call, so that the code in your program calls the library which does the system call.